# Angular Cli with POM - Maven

Tags: angular, maven, jenkins

I have a project using Spring Boot and Angular 8.
I can build it without problem ,here is how i am building the front-end inside POM:

`
                
                com.github.eirslett
                frontend-maven-plugin
                1.6

```
        <!--    <skip>true</skip>-->

                <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
                <nodeVersion>v10.13.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>ng prod </id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run prod</arguments>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

`

My question is,i need to deploy this with Jenkins,what do i need to add to the POM so Angular-CLI is installed on Jenkins?
Because i guess,the "NG" command will not be found in Jenkins.
How do i resolve this?

Comment: I guess if i have @angular/cli inside my devDependencies it s all i need maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the front-end build section from my POM.
It installs node and npm (so that you don't have to have it pre-installed in Jenkins),
runs Sonar, and then does a production build of the Angular code.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>

        <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>v12.4.0</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
            <!-- optional: where to download node and npm from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
            <!--  <downloadRoot>http://myproxy.example.org/nodejs/dist/</downloadRoot> -->
            <workingDirectory>src/main/javascript</workingDirectory>
            <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            <srcdir>${basedir}/src/main/javascript</srcdir>
            <outputdir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static</outputdir>
            <!-- define skipFrontend as true or false in your .m2/settings.xml, in a profile -->
            <skip>${skipFrontend}</skip>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>npm install</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>javascript sonar</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- define skipFrontend as true or false in your .m2/settings.xml, in a profile -->
                    <skip>${skipSonar}</skip>
                    <arguments>run-script sonar</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>javascript build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>run-script build-prod</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

        </executions>

    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks! But does Jenkins need to have the angular Cli? I think using "run" it uses the angular Cli you have in devDependencies.

Comment: No, the cli is installed locally by the build. It gets run out of the node_modules directory.